# determine the transformation matrix rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

> Suppose $T$ is a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.
>   Find the matrix $A$ that induces $T$ if $T$ is the (counter-clockwise) rotation by $\tfrac{3}{4}\pi$.

I am not sure how to begin to find a matrix that is $2\times 2$ for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The rotation matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta) &\cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$.

---

But blindly applying this formula doesn't teach you the most important part of linear transformations.

> ANY linear transformation matrix is defined by where it takes the unit
>   vectors.

This linear transformation $T$ that is a counterclockwise rotation takes $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta)\\\sin(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix} -\sin(\theta)\\\cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$. You can confirm this on your own using geometry.

And this works for ANY linear transformation.